# How To Ask Remote Desktop Password After Connection

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-server-2022

I would like in a windows server 2022 to edit the login behaviour of remote desktop.

I've been told that it is possible to ask for password AFTER the connection has been established.
In order to obtain that I should edit a gpo inside the machine.

Let me explain, right now the password is asked before the connection is established, but what i want to achieve is that the password is asked at a login screen on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the server i did a gpo from:
local computer policy, computer configuration, admininistrative template, windows component, remote desktop services, remote desktop session host, security, require use of specific security layer for remote rdp connection.
Enable and select RDP.
Then from the Allow connections only from computers running remote destkop with network level authentication (recommended), uncheck that box.

Answer (score 2):

You can by disabling `CredSSP`.
I guess the quickest way would be by creating an RDP file and add the option `enablecredsspsupport:i:0` at the bottom.
[image]

[image]

On the server you want to connect you need disable NLA here by unchecking this box:
[image]

Be aware, disabling security features like this always adds some risks.